# Populating column B with calculated values based on column A with single statement

Tags: mysql

I need to take the value from column A, calculate something and insert the result into column B. The rows in column A contain a lot of duplicates. So maybe this can be used to an advantage. If possible this should be done in a single statement.

Example:

This is what the `table1` looks like in the beginning:

```
columnA          columnB
-------------------------
'  apple'   
' melon '   
'  apple'   
' melon '
```

The strings in `columnA` do have unnecessary whitespaces and the rows in `columnB` are empty.

And this is what `table1` should look like in the end:

```
columnA          columnB
-------------------------
'  apple'        'apple'
' melon '        'melon'   
'  apple'        'apple'
' melon '        'melon'
```

The rows in `columnB` are populated with the trimmed versions of the strings in `columnA`.

Is it possible to do this in one statement?

Answer:
The answer from @Ergest Basha made it clear, that this can be done with a simple statement:

```
UPDATE table1 SET columnB =  TRIM(columnA);
```

Thanks!

Comment: An easy way to do this is to create a new temporary table (`fruitamount_normalized`) to insert the `newname` values into (so each row is unique), and then run a second query to update the `amount` values in that table. Then delete your old table and rename your new one to `fruitamount`. That way you don't need to worry about deleting duplicate rows in your old table.

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for? Are you wanting to `UPDATE` your `fruitamounts` table with the new data? Or do you want to only `SELECT amount, newname` using the trimmed values?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: I want to populate (UPDATE) column 'newname'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question to make it more clear and lean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `newcolumn` and if you do not have an id autoincrement you can add it ,too.

```
CREATE TABLE fruitamount(
id INT,
name varchar(10),
amount int);

insert into fruitamount values
(1,'  apple',2),
(2,' melon ',5),
(3,'  apple',1),
(4,' melon ',4);

alter table fruitamount add  column newcolumn varchar(10) ;

update fruitamount set newcolumn = TRIM(name) ;
```

After update you can drop the column:

```
alter table fruitamount drop  column name  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question to make it more clear and lean.

Comment: Your answer includes what I was looking for:
`UPDATE table1 SET columnB =  TRIM(columnA);`
(using the example from the edited question) Maybe you want to edit your answer to show exactly that code. Thanks!

Comment: I meant, maybe you want to adapt your answer to fit the simplyfied and updated question. I changed the example to make everything more clear and lean. Just only include `UPDATE table1 SET columnB =  TRIM(columnA);` in your answer. It would fit perfect and be immediately clear to every visitor.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what the end result you're looking for is, but here are a few options:

*Note: the extra whitespace in the `name` columns doesn't appear on stackoverflow.com*

[1. Create a new table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/32BV6nmEotR6qJotBLDzMp/1). Select the normalized data and insert it into a new (temporary) table. Then drop the old table and rename the new table.

```
/* show initial table */
SELECT * FROM fruitamount;

/* create a new table with the normalized data */
CREATE TABLE fruitamount_normalized AS
SELECT
    SUM(amount) as amount,
    TRIM(name) AS newname
FROM fruitamount
GROUP BY TRIM(name);

/* delete the old table */
DROP TABLE fruitamount;

/* rename the new table */
RENAME TABLE fruitamount_normalized TO fruitamount;

/* show new table/data */
SELECT * FROM fruitamount;
```

| amount | newname |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | apple |
| 9 | melon |

[2. Select summed/trimmed data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/32BV6nmEotR6qJotBLDzMp/4)

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) as amount,
    TRIM(name) AS newname
FROM fruitamount
GROUP BY TRIM(name);
```

| amount | newname |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | apple |
| 9 | melon |

[3. Update table and then select DISTINCT data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/32BV6nmEotR6qJotBLDzMp/3). This will cause duplicate rows which will need to be cleaned up separately.

```
/*
  update the fruitamount table with the new values
*/
UPDATE fruitamount fa
JOIN (
  SELECT
      SUM(amount) as amount,
      TRIM(name) AS newname
  FROM fruitamount
  GROUP BY TRIM(name)
) fa2
SET fa.amount = fa2.amount, fa.newname = fa2.newname WHERE TRIM(name) = fa2.newname;

/* show updated table */
SELECT * FROM fruitamount;

/* only select distinct rows */
SELECT DISTINCT amount, newname FROM fruitamount;
```

| name | amount | newname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 3 | apple |
| melon | 9 | melon |
| apple | 3 | apple |
| melon | 9 | melon |

| amount | newname |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | apple |
| 9 | melon |

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question to make it more clear and lean.